# Software to solve system of linear equations in non-standard form

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab, wolfram-alpha

Is there software to use to solve more than 4 simultaneous linear equations? Wolfram Alpha is nice but it can only do up to 4? Wolfram Alpha is nice because it can handle a non-standard form, but limited to 4 equations.

Most software only seems to handle standard form like so:

```
Ax = b
```

My equations look like so:

```
P=0.4
s0 = (1-P)*s1
s1 = (1-P)*s2 + P*s0
s2 = (1-P)*s3 + P*s1
s3 = (1-P)*s4 + P*s2
s4 = P*s3
```

It's annoying at best to try to format them into an Ax=b form. Internally software implementations probably convert it to matrix form, but it would be nice to just feed it what I have.

Comment: yeah my TI-89 can do what I want, but it's cumbersome and time-consuming to enter that info. Looking for something more programmatic. Also you can just put the P=0.4 as another arg in the linear equation list fyi.

Comment: Matlab's Symbolic Math Toolbox: `P=0.4;` `syms s0 s1 s2 s3 s4;` `solve([s0==(1-P)*s1,s1==(1-P)*s2+P*s0,s2==(1-P)*s3+P*s1,s3==(1-P)*s4+P*s2,s4==P*s3],[s0,s1,s2,s3,s4]`